# Pass function arguments to Object.assign

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function to compose an object from other objects, and I am passing arguments to the function - initially an object literal, and then the objects I want to compose to extent the object:

```
composeFunc({}, obj1, obj2, obj3);
```

The number of args passed is optional, how do I then pass the args to `Object.assign()` starting at the 2nd arg. So the function would resemble the following:

```
function composeObj(objs) {
    return Object.assign(arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3]... etc);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have already passed argument from 2nd as `arguments` is an array of arguments passed to function;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7: It's not an array, just array-like (which is relevant to the question). But I think the example was just to show the concept of what they wanted to do. The issue being that the number of arguments is variable.

Comment: @le-moi `arguments` is an special array having all passed arguments in it;

Comment: @le-moi Why do you want to skip the first argument? In your example, it would be important not to, assuming `composeObj` and `composeFunc` are the same function.

Comment: If you're using ES2015, you might want to switch your accepted answer to [Thomas'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36663564/157247). Rest args are the way to go in ES2015.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using ES2015 rather than just a shim<s>, you can use spread notation, `Array.from`, and `slice`:</s>

```
function composeObj(objs) {
    return Object.assign(...Array.from(arguments).slice(1));
}
```

Or just using `slice` directly rather than after `Array.from`:

```
function composeObj(objs) {
    return Object.assign(...Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

...see [Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36663564/157247) using rest args, as that's the right way to do this in ES2015.

If you're not using ES2015, you can do the same thing with just a shimmed `Object.assign` via `apply`:

```
function composeObj(objs) {
    return Object.assign.apply(Object, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

There, we're using `Function#apply` instead of the spread operator (since ES5 and earlier don't have the spread operator). `Function#apply` calls the function you call it on using the first argument as `this` during the call, and using the array (or array-like thing) you give it as a second argument as the arguments for the call.

So say you have:

```
obj.foo(1, 2, 3);
```

The equivalent using `Function#apply` is:

```
obj.foo.apply(obj, [1, 2, 3]);
```

The first argument, `obj`, tells `apply` what to use as `this` during the call. The second argument is an array of arguments to use.

But if you use the spread operator, there's no need, it spreads out its array-like operand into discrete arguments.

Comment: Bingo, thanks TJ. Could you talk me through what is going on, if you don't mind? 
Why do we call apply on Object.assign()? Also why is Object the first arg to apply? 
Trying to work out in my head what is going on - is the apply used to deal with the returned arguments because they are converted to an Array?

Comment: @LeMoi: I've added to the end to explain that, but if you're using the spread operator from ES2015, you don't need to use `apply`.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's brilliant :)

Comment: It seems that the `Array#slice` can be eliminated by `Function.call.apply(Object.assign, arguments)`

Comment: `Function.call.apply(Object.assign, arguments)` will "skip the first argument" but it does not require to create a new array...

Comment: The question on my head is that ..`assign` is "static" method of `Object`..
like we can do this `Math.min.apply(anyCtx, numbersArray)`...Why the `this` is important?

Comment: @user943702: Yeah, looking at [`Object.assign`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.assign), in that specific case, it may well work, as those steps don't reference `this`. But there are several "static"-seeming methods that do need `this` to be set correctly. I wouldn't use that pattern. But it does seem to work (at least on Chrome and from the spec) in this specific case.

Comment: If you're using ES6, you'd use rest parameters instead of slicing `arguments` :-)

Comment: @Bergi: That's a good point. Where was my head?! Fixed. Actually, un-fixed now, as I see Thomas has posted that answer; instead, just linked to it.

Answer (score 4):

ES2015:

```
function composeObj(objs, ...rest){
  return Object.assign(...rest);
}
```

`rest` will be a true array of all of the arguments starting from the second one.

And the Babel-output:

```
function composeObj(objs) {
  for (var _len = arguments.length, rest = Array(_len > 1 ? _len - 1 : 0), _key = 1; _key < _len; _key++) {
    rest[_key - 1] = arguments[_key];
  }

  return Object.assign.apply(Object, rest);
}
```

This seems to be a utility-function that might be used all over the place. As soon as you pass `arguments` to an other function like `Array.prototype.slice()` or `Array.from()`, `composeObj` won't be optimized by the JS-compiler anymore. So, don't do that.

Everything else has already been said on T.J. Crowders Answer and the comments; just showing the better implementation.

Comment: If the OP is using ES2015, this should be the accepted answer, and anyone using ES2015 with a similar problem should be following this advice. (Where was my head?)